# What's the best way to start a project in mercurial when you already have files in the project?

Tags: mercurial, project-management, project

I'm starting with Mercurial. I'm reading the [mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) but still have a question.

I've started my project month ago, and i have a lot of files and directories in it. Now, i want to use Mercurial and made myself an account in bitbucket. Now, i want to set this project up in Bitbucket. How can i add all those files to the bitbucket repo?

This is what i was thinking i could do:
I could try to (1) clone the empty repo (from bitbucket) (1) copy all files into that directory, (3) issue an "hg add" and after that (4) commiting.

Maybe you have a better way to do this.

Thanks!

(1)

```
hg clone https://ME@bitbucket.org/ME/myproject
```

(2)

```
cp existing-project/* myproject/
cd myproject
```

(3)

```
hg add
```

(4)

```
hg commit -u ME
```

(5)

```
hg push (i think i have to do this to make the changes visible)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply `hg init`, `hg add`, and `hg commit` in the original project folder, then edit `~/project/.hg/hgrc` to add a default-push location of your bitbucket repo (you can clone it to a temporary folder to get the hgrc created for you which you can copy into your project, even, without needing to RTFM for the right syntax.)

Because of the distributed nature of mercurial, this hgrc entry is the only thing relating your local repo to bitbucket at all; you can even `hg push https://ME@bitbucket.org/ME/myproject` without making the link explicit anywhere. Each copy of a repository is completely self-sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Wooble. Seems real simple!

Answer (score 3):

Wooble's answer is ok, but it's missing something, so I'm supplementing here.

When you first create an empty repository (by `hg init` or creating on bitbucket), it has no identity. However, as soon as it has any changesets, it has an identity and you can only push/pull between it and repositories that share that identity.

If you had 2 repositories A and B for separate projects, you wouldn't be able push/pull between them. Once you create a new repository on bitbucket you can push changesets from either A or B to that repo **once**. If you push changes from B that first time, the bitbucket repository is now related to B. You can't then push changesets from A into it, or pull changesets into A from it.

So when Wooble says,

> ...this hgrc entry is the only thing relating your local repo to bitbucket at all;

That is correct while it is still empty as it is not related to any repositories until it has changesets. And you still need that address to be able to push/pull between your local repo and the bitbucket repo, but once you've pushed changesets to it it also has that identity that relates it to your local repo.